# Is this possible in Google Maps? Drawing a box manually on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on integrating Google Maps into a web application and I have a question of possibility.

I am using  ASP .Net 4.0 as the basis for the code, but i suspect i will have to use JavaScript to achieve most of this, which is. Basically I want to display a bunch of markers on a map from Lat Long locations i have stored in a database, then have the user be able to draw a box on the map with the mouse, then get back the lat long of the four corners of the box.

If anyone knows how i could do this this would be of great help to me!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity of the Google Maps API has kept me scared for years. Recently I stumbled upon a jQuery plugin called [GMap3](http://gmap3.net/) that does a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

I would suggest that after initializing and all that, you print a Javascript block from your .NET code, with something like this:

```js
var markersFromDatabase = [
    [60.164967,24.94758],
    [59.956495, 10.764599]
    //etc. This array should be printed from your serverside code
];
var markersToBeAdded = [];
jQuery.each(markersFromDatabase, function(indexOfItem, valueOfItem){
    markersToBeAdded.push({
        lat:valueOfItem[0],
        lng:valueOfItem[1],
        options: {
            draggable: false,
            icon: "img/your_awesome_icon.png",
            title: "This is an icon from my database!"
        }
    });
});
jQuery("#map_canvas").gmap3(
    { action: 'addMarkers',
        markers: markersToBeAdded
    }
);
```

**Edit:** I realize now that I only answered half of your question. I'm afraid I have no apparent answer to the selection box. I suspect that you can use [addRectangle](http://gmap3.net/api/add-rectangle.html) or, in a worst case scenario, [addFixPanel](http://gmap3.net/api/add-fix-panel.html) that lets you add a transparent `<div>` over your map canvas (and then trigger mouse events for that).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with Google Maps API 3's overlay editable feature.

[Google Maps Overlay Editable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#editable)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "How to select multiple markers with a rectangle", you can do something like this:

```
var markers = []; // This array must be filled with your data
var rectangles = [];
var triggeredMarkers = [];
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', updateSelection);

function updateSelection(rectangle){
   var lat_max = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
   var lat_min = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
   var lng_max = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
   var lng_min = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
   rectangles.push(rectangle);

   for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
     if((lat_min < markers[i].getPosition().lat() ? (markers[i].getPosition().lat() < lat_max ? true:false):false)
       && (lng_min < markers[i].getPosition().lng() ? (markers[i].getPosition().lng() < lng_max ? true:false):false)){
       triggeredMarkers.push(markers[i]);
     }
   }
}
```

The `rectangles` array is used to hold rectangles in order to be able to erase them later.

But if you just want a simple function that handle Polygons, there is [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) that really can be helpful for you. It can be used like this:

```
var markers = [];
var polygones = [];
var triggeredMarkers = [];
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', updateSelection);

function updateSelection(polygon){
   polygones.push(polygon);

   for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
    if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(markers[i].getPosition(),polygon)){
       triggeredMarkers.push(markers[i]);
     }
   }
}
```

For rectangles and circles there's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22343573/8658039) that can help you.