# How to indicate that a point is inside the circle or rectangle by geometry library in Google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Look at this:

```
if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLatitude[counter1], arrayLongitude[counter1]), polygon))
{
}
```

This is the condition to indicates that a point is inside the polygon or no.
I'm looking for something similar but for circle or rectangle.

something like this:

```
if(google.maps.geometry.circle.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLatitude[counter1], arrayLongitude[counter1]), circle)
{
}
```

Or for rectangle:

```
if(google.maps.geometry.rectangle.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLatitude[counter1], arrayLongitude[counter1]), rectangle)
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Circle) and [Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Rectangle) have method

> getBounds()   LatLngBounds    Returns the bounds of this rectangle.

Try call method getBounds() witch return [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) item. It has method

> contains(latLng:LatLng)    boolean Returns true if the given lat/lng is in this bounds.

something like

```
(new google.maps.Circle({center: new google.maps.LatLng(YOUR_LAT, YOUR_LNG),radius: YOUR_RADIUS})).getBounds().contains(google.maps.LatLng(POINT_LAT, POINT_LNG))
```

Hope it is what you need

Comment: Thanks. I need something to work with 'geometry' library. Does it?

Comment: No. It's standart GM functionality. Just create object ( Circle or Rectangle with parametrs you need and call method to check if point inside figure ). Possible  i didn't understand question, sorry ? Can you give example what you need at jsbin or plunker ?

Comment: I want a method like this: var distanceInMetres = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngCircleCenter, latLngPoint); Does it work?

Comment: Ow, than you must to declare circle radius ( circle defined by center and radius, not only center )

Comment: Something like that   


(new google.maps.Circle({center: new google.maps.LatLng(YOUR_LAT, YOUR_LNG),radius: YOUR_RADIUS})).getBounds().contains(google.maps.LatLng(POINT_LAT, POINT_LNG))

Answer (score 0):

Important notice: If you don't set getSouthWest and getNorth... it always return false:
[Google Maps v3 map.getBounds().containsLatLng is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899711/google-maps-v3-map-getbounds-containslatlng-is-not-a-function)

```
var temp_rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(array_shapes_object[counter].getSouthWestLat, array_shapes_object[counter].getSouthWestLng),
    new google.maps.LatLng(array_shapes_object[counter].getNorthEastLat, array_shapes_object[counter].getNorthEastLng))
});

if(temp_rectangle.getBounds().contains(new google.maps.LatLng(arrayLatitude[counter1], arrayLongitude[counter1])))
{
    alert("Inside");
}
else
{
    alert("Outside");
}
```